# Getting undefined is not a function while using useState

Tags: reactjs

I copied simple carousel from `chakra ui` templates and there is an error:

```
Server Error
TypeError: undefined is not a function
7 |   // As we have used custom buttons, we need a reference variable to
   8 |   // change the state
>  9 |   const [slider, setSlider] = (React.useState < Slider) | (null > null);
```

Orignal useState function from chakra ui template:

```
const [slider, setSlider] = React.useState<Slider | null>(null);
```

When I save in VS Code it changes to:

```
const [slider, setSlider] = (React.useState < Slider) | (null > null);
```

I got Prettier - code formatter v.9.2.0. and probably it changes the code, but is it still correct? I use `react-slick` library to create  a carousel.

Comment: `const [slider, setSlider] = (React.useState < Slider) | (null > null`
this is not correct
it should be like
`const [value, setValue]= React.useState<type>(value to set initially)`

Comment: const [slider, setSlider] = React.useState(initialValue), it is what I've learnt, but why prettier change this to incorrect code syntax?

Comment: and what it is this syntax? React.useState<Slider | null>(null). Why there are < and > instead of ( and ) ?

Comment: check you prettier setting or add custom file in your code `.prettierrc` with some code 
`{
    "singleQuote": true,
    "semi": true,
    "trailingComma": "all",
    "arrowParens": "always",
    "endOfLine": "auto"
}`

Comment: are you using JS or TS with React?

Comment: these `<>` are and content in between we are defining type of state you created. we are using this with React TS

Comment: I use Javascript with React. What is the way to write it in JS? I left it like this `const [slider, setSlider] = React.useState(null)` and it renders the carousel, anyway

Comment: It seems like you've blindly copied a _TypeScript_ snippet then mangled it until it's minimally valid syntax, but now makes no sense semantically.

Comment: yes with Javascript you no need to define type

Comment: Ok, thank you for your explanation. Am I supposed to delete this question or I edit and post the right code or answer my question by myself, lol xD?